# loading video to a view from Library/Caches

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, video

for my app I want the user to record a video which will be stored in the caches directory for repeated use throughout the application.

```
NSString *DestFilename = @ "output.mov";

//Set the file save to URL
NSLog(@"Starting recording to file: %@", DestFilename);
NSString *DestPath;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
DestPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
DestPath = [DestPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:DestFilename];

NSURL* saveLocationURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:DestPath];
[MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:saveLocationURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

The NSLog says:

`url = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BD41ABB0-77BA-4872-B447-07906A3C6FA7/Library/Caches/output.mov`

How can I load or possibly embed this video into one of the ViewControllers in my storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your video URL is there, so you can load the video into your view controller and play it in 2 possible approaches: using MPMoviePlayerController or AVPlayer

For example from your view controller

```
    //The first approach
    self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:saveLocationURL];
    [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];

    [self.moviePlayerController play];

    //The second approach
    self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:saveLocationURL];
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
    [self.player play];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This looks great, much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. For further implementation, you should consider on handling some observation on video playback statuses such as video did start, did end, statuses changes and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it likely that I will be able to embed this solution into another view using a container view or something? I don't need the controls or anything to be visible I just want to show the video as a smaller part of a view.

Comment: Yeah, you can see my code that I added video view into the view of view controller, if you want it displays as a part of a view, just simply create a container view as you said or adjust the frame accordingly.